# When i click on imageview it should change to another image view in a listview

Tags: android

I have a listview with an imageview in each row.When i click on imageview it should change to another image view. pls help me with coding.

Comment: why don't you replace the image of  imageview onclick?

Comment: Please be more concrete with asking your questions, what you actually don't understand? "please help me with coding" is not a good question at all.

Comment: no i tried that.its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
lv_ArchivePartylist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.archive_ListView01);
    lv_ArchivePartylist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
view.findViewById(R.id.imageview).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home);
}
}
```

Comment: can u pls tell which is the replaced image view(home or imageview)

Comment: Image view is same only the image inside the Imageview is changed.
At first it was displaying imageview.jpg and then it displays home.jpg